# CSS centering content add by pseudo-element after

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I know there is a bunch of post which treats of the question, but my case is different.

I have a palette of colors (circles), when I click on a circle i add content (check mark) by adding a class selector which have an after pseudo-element:

The circle css  parent ( ul element):

```
.lk-color-chooser__color {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
}
```

The child element (li the circle):

```
.lk-color-chooser__color:last-child {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
 }
```

On the selection of a circle i add this class :

```
.color__selected {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.color__selected:after{
  content: "✔";
  margin-left: 15%;
  top: 20;
  color:#000000;
}
```

And when is not selected I remove `color__selected` and add this class:

```
.color__not_selected {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
}
```

Thus when clicked, I add a check to the circle when clicked again I remove it.

My problem is that the added check mark isn't centred inside the circle.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hCgwX4bxsd6HiZhhgDKZ?p=preview) of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `position:relative;` in the container for the circle.

then for your after give it a set height and width and `position absolute;right:0;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;`

Whats happening here is your telling the tick to act absolutely relative to the LI container and using the o positioning and auto margin will keep it dead center all ways this technique will work for anything.

That will center the tick for you regardless of the size of the circle.

---

```css
.color__selected_black:after {
  content: "✔";
  /* margin-left: 15%; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 12px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
}
.lk-color-chooser__color {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add line height for this class like this: **[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fxTqQJA6ilBsvshynPi?p=preview)**

```
.lk-color-chooser__color {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  line-height:30px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
}
```

Comment: Line height is not actually centering it though your just padding out the top.